# Not getting return value from PowerShell function

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I'm trying to clean up some PowerShell scripts and I'm moving inline functions into their own files. I'm not getting the return value when using the file-based approach.

The function I'm using is

```
function IsModuleInstalled
{
    param
    (
        [string]$moduleName
    )
    if(Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name $moduleName)
    {
        Write-Host "$moduleName Module is installed"
        return $true
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "$moduleName Module is not installed"
        return $false
    }
}
```

When it's left as an inline function then it returns a true/false value.

```
$val = IsModuleInstalled -moduleName "module"
Write-Host "val = $val" # "val = False"
```

When I move it to its own file and use dot sourcing I'm not getting a value.

```
$val = . $PSScriptRoot\..\Functions\IsModuleInstalled.ps1; IsModuleInstalled -ModuleName "module"
Write-Host "val = $val" # "val = "
```

I've tried using return and Write-Output. How can I fix this?

Comment: `$val = . $PSScriptRoot\..\Functions\IsModuleInstalled.ps1; IsModuleInstalled -ModuleName "module"` are 2 statements not one. what you wanted is `. $PSScriptRoot\..\Functions\IsModuleInstalled.ps1; $val = IsModuleInstalled -ModuleName "module"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you move your function to its own file and then dot-source it, you're essentially importing the function into your current session or script. The dot-sourcing itself doesn't execute the function; it just makes the function available to be called. When you dot-source and then immediately try to execute the function, the return value of the dot-sourcing (which is nothing) is being assigned to `$val`, not the return value of the function.

To Fix it:

1. First, dot-source the file to import the function.
2. Then, call the function and capture its return value.

corrected code:

```
# Dot-source the function file to import the function
. $PSScriptRoot\..\Functions\IsModuleInstalled.ps1

# Now call the function and capture its return value
$val = IsModuleInstalled -ModuleName "module"

Write-Host "val = $val"
```

This way, the function's return value will be correctly assigned to `$val`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation. I knew it was something obvious.